# batch size effect on tf.keras.Model.evaluate(...)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras

I have just stumbled upon a really weird observation. I load same model + same dataset.
And run `model.evaluate()`. First I set `batch_size=1024` and result was `{"accuracy": 0.009400000795722008}`. After few more tries I decreased it to `batch_size=8` and got `{accuracy: 0.49239999055862427}`. Any ideas why this could happen?

Here's a snipped of evaluation:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from absl import app, flags

FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
flags.DEFINE_integer("batch_size", default=16, help="Batch Size of dataset")
flags.DEFINE_bool("use_xla", default=False, help="Use XLA compiler yes/no")
...

def eval_accuracy(model: tf.keras.Model):
    # No shuffle so we can restore the state
    dataset = tfds.load(
        "imagenet_v2",
        as_supervised=True,
        shuffle_files=True,
        batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
        split=["test"],
    )

    dataset = dataset[0]

    dataset = (
        dataset
        .map(lambda x, y: (tf.image.resize(x, (224, 224)), y))
        .cache()
        .prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    )
    result = model.evaluate(dataset, return_dict=True)

def main(*args, **kwargs):
    model: tf.keras.Model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0()
    model.run_eagerly = False
    model.compile(
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
        metrics=["accuracy"],
        jit_compile=FLAGS.use_xla,
    )
    if FLAGS.metric == "accuracy":
        return eval_accuracy(model)
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(main)
```

Comment: Was that the final accuracy after many epochs? Or just a few? The difference is more noticeable when the training period is shorter.

Comment: I'm not training the model. As per [Keras](https://keras.io/api/applications/efficientnet/#efficientnetb0-function) default value for weights is `weights='imagenet'`. I just load pre-trained model, and run evaluation on [imagenet subset](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/imagenet_v2).